# largest known twin semiprimes and consecutive semiprimes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, semiprimes

What are the largest known semiprimes differing by 2?  What is the largest known pair of consecutive numbers that are both semiprimes?  Has anyone computed this?

Comment: Dana Jacobsen might have.

Comment: Any idea where this can be seen?

Comment: Mersenneforum. I think they sometimes visit stackexchange.

Comment: I'll see if I can find.  THANxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: If you have consecutive semiprimes, one of them must be even and hence equal to $2p$.

Comment: I tired to register at mersenneforum with NO luck.  It may be that twin primes get all the attention, leaving any talk about semiprimes to  never happen.

Comment: I just now failed at trying to contact Jacobsen.  It is my suspicion that my question is classified by the Pentagon for fear that either the Chinese or Iranians will find out the answer.

Comment: Only with great luck we can beat the following construction of huge pairs of semiprimes  : If $2n+1$ and $3n+2$ are both prime , then $3(2n+1)$ and $2(3n+2)$ are consecutive semiprimes. If $5n+1$ and $3n+1$ are both prime, then $3(5n+1)$ and $5(3n+1)$ are semiprimes with difference $2$. Maybe someone knows a pair that is so huge that it cannot be beaten with my construction in practice, but I have doubts.

Comment: How to get the Mersenne gang interested in this?  Two semiprimes differing by 2 or by 1 should amuse them.

Comment: @J.M.Bergot Enzo Creti is in this forum. I can ask him whether he can ask them.

Comment: @DanaJ can you help these poor souls.

Comment: I suspect that my quiry has not been examined by any other "poor souls."